# overflow + box-shadow

Tags: css, css3

Если элемент находится в div'е, которому задан `overflow: hidden`, то box-shadow начинает вести себя неправильно.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksLuxw13/)

```css
input {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px
}

input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #45749d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #588bb7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #588bb7;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #588bb7;
}

.o {
  overflow: hidden
}

.l {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="o">
  <div class="l">
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="l">
    test
  </div>
</div>

Что-то ещё.
```

Есть вариант, использовать `padding` и тогда тень появляется как надо, но не хотелось бы решить это так.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksLuxw13/1/)

```css
input {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px
}

input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #45749d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #588bb7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #588bb7;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #588bb7;
}

.o {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px
}

.l {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="o">
  <div class="l">
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="l">
    test
  </div>
</div>

Что-то ещё.
```

Есть идеи, как решить это без использования отступов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` - Отображается только область внутри элемента, остальное будет скрыто

вместо `overflow: hidden` в данном случае лучше использовать **clearfix** - для отмены обтекания

http://jsfiddle.net/asxxmubL/

```css
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

input {background: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #cccccc; outline: none; width: 50px; height: 20px}
input:focus {border: 1px solid #45749d; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #588bb7; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #588bb7; box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #588bb7;}

.o {}
.l {float: left; margin-right: 10px}
```

```html
<div class="o clearfix">
    <div class="l">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
        
    <div class="l">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: кривое решение. Стоит добавить текст после div и он не там, где нужно. С overflow такого не было. http://jsfiddle.net/Ls2qcj7o/1/

Comment: так? http://jsfiddle.net/b0frjwhu/

Comment: ага. Спасибо огромное.